# Can I hide a Category (and its subcategories) from the sidebar?

Tags: wordpress

I put the widget category on the primary sidebar, from the dashboard. Than, on code, I use :

```
<?php get_sidebar('left'); ?>
```

and it create the code for the categories. Now, I'd like to hide the category with tag_ID=6, and all of its subcategories.

How can I do it?

Tried this [tutorial](http://www.lancelhoff.com/how-to-hide-wordpress-categories/), but seems that I don't have the `$cat_args = "orderby=name&show_count={$c}&hierarchical={$h}";` line? I'm on last version of WordPress, 3.4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial seems outdated, so I wouldn't rely on that. It is not necessary to hack around in the WordPress-source - create a simple Plugin which hooks into the right filters.

In your case those filters are `widget_categories_dropdown_args` (when you select "Display as dropdown" in the Widget-options) and [`widget_categories_args`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/widget_categories_args) (if the Widgets displays the list as normal text with links).

With that knowledge you can now code the actual plugin (I've called it Myplugin, I think you should rename it) - just put that PHP code into the file `wp-content/plugins/myplugin.php`:

```
<?php
/**
 * @package Myplugin
 * @version 1.0
 */
/*
Plugin Name: Myplugin
Plugin URI: http://example.com
Description: 
Author: You
Version: 1.0
Author URI: http://example.com
*/

// Create a list with the ID's of all children for 
// the given category-id
function myplugin_recursive_filter($catid) {
    $result = array($catid);

    $cats = get_categories(array(
        'child_of' => $catid,
    ));

    foreach($cats as $category) {
        $result[] = $category->cat_ID;
    }

    return implode(",", $result);
}

// Actual filter function. Just set the "exclude" 
// entry to a comma separated list of category ID's 
// to hide.
function myplugin_filter_categories_args($args) {
    // 6 is the "tag_ID"
    $args['exclude'] = myplugin_recursive_filter(6);

    // or hard code the list like that:
    //$args['exclude'] = '6,10,11,12';
    // but you'd have to include the ID's of the
    // children, because "eclude" is not recursive.
    return $args;
}

// Register the filter to the relevant tags
add_filter('widget_categories_dropdown_args',
    'myplugin_filter_categories_args', 10, 1);

add_filter('widget_categories_args',
    'myplugin_filter_categories_args', 10, 1);
```

The function `myplugin_recursive_filter` is necessary, because the `exclude`-entry is not recursive (except if you check "Show hierarchy" in the widget options). If your categories don't change that much you could replace function call with a hard-coded list of ID's (with the children) for better performance.